# Diskspace on Shared Folder using kernel32 dll compared to property

Tags: c#, windows, explorer, kernel32

I have a shared folder on a network where I want to know the total size of it as well as the percentage of memory used from a specific folder.

At the moment I am using this code.

```
namespace DiskFreeSpaceEx
{
    internal class FreeSpace
    {
        [DllImport("kernel32")]
        public static extern int GetDiskFreeSpaceEx(string lpDirectoryName, ref long lpFreeBytesAvailable, ref long lpTotalNumberOfBytes, ref long lpTotalNumberOfFreeBytes);
        const string RootPathName = @"\\Server\Sharename\Folder\Subfolder\...\TargetFolder";
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            long freeBytesAvailable = 0;
            long totalNumberOfBytes = 0;
            long totalNumberOfFreeBytes = 0;

            GetDiskFreeSpaceEx(RootPathName, ref freeBytesAvailable, ref
               totalNumberOfBytes, ref totalNumberOfFreeBytes);

            Console.WriteLine("{0}\t{1}\t{2}\t{3}", RootPathName,
                freeBytesAvailable, totalNumberOfBytes, totalNumberOfFreeBytes);

            long percentage = (totalNumberOfBytes - freeBytesAvailable) * 100 / totalNumberOfBytes;

            Console.WriteLine(percentage.ToString());
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

With this configuration I get a usage of 86% (That means 86% of its capacity is filled with data and ~14% is free)

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/windows/desktop/api/FileAPI/nf-fileapi-getdiskfreespaceexa

But then I figured out a 99.8% Storage using the folders properties via Explorer. What does it mean? Which is more trustful?

Comment: what does a 3rd party app like windirstat say?

Comment: Tha function is used to determine how much total disk space and free disk space is available to the caller, the User associated with the calling thread. Maybe see the WMI [Win32_LogicalDisk](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/cimwin32prov/win32-logicaldisk) and [Win32_MappedLogicalDisk](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/cimwin32prov/win32-mappedlogicaldisk) classes. It depends on what you want to know.

Comment: I am not allowed to use 3rd Party Tools...

@Jimi I want to know the total capacity of the network drive and I want to know the size of the specific folder. Afterwards I can calculate the percentage of this specific folder compared to the total size. Something like Console.WriteLine("This Folder used {0}% of the shared Folder", percentage).

Comment: What 3rd party tools are you referring to? What I linked is related to the Microsoft's [System.Management](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management)  Namespace, directly available adding a reference to the `System.Management` assembly.

Comment: I meant JohnB sorry.

Comment: To get the total size of all files in a Directory, you need to enumerate it: `var totalFilesSize = new DirectoryInfo(@"[Path]").EnumerateFiles().Sum(f => f.Length);`

Comment: @Jimi
Doesn't it take too long if I have e.g. millions of files?

Comment: Yes, it does. You'll get old :) You'll probably need to use disc Quotas to assign a defined space to that user, so `GetDiskFreeSpaceEx` *might* work as expected, if the user has a quota in that network folder only.

Comment: Back to the question, do you know why my code shows for example 86% storage, while the property using the explorer shows something else?